# Phoenix LiveReload does nothing when working with Vagrant

Tags: vagrant, elixir, phoenix-framework, macos-sierra, livereload

Using the following and trying to create & run a Phoenix app.

```
OS(Host): MacOS Sierra 10.12.4
OS(Guest): Ubuntu Xenial 16.04
Vagrant 1.9.4
VirtualBox 5.0.24
Phoenix 1.3.0-rc1
Elixir 1.4.2
Sublime Text 3
Safari 10.1
Chrome 58.0
Firefox 58.0.2
```

The Phoenix server fires up on the Guest OS, i can access the app from the Host in the browser, but the issue comes, when I make changes to a CSS file.

I go to the Sublime and change the file `assets/css/app.css`. After I change it, corresponding changes are reflected in `private/static/css/app.css` just fine, but here are the issues:

- The Live Reload feature doesn't work.
- Even if I do a hard refresh in the browser, I don't see that CSS changes reflected.

So, after googling a bit, instead of editing the CSS file on the Host OS, I ssh'd into the Guest OS(Ubuntu) & started editing the CSS file in it. Saved it. And I was able to see entries in the server logs, that it had recompiled the `assets/css/app.css` file like so:

`[debug] Live reload: priv/static/css/app.css
01:40:28 - info: compiled app.css and 3 cached files into app.css in 99 ms
[info] GET /`

The browser did a refresh, but to my surprise, the CSS changes were still not reflected, which was very weird.

So, I thought of running the app on the Host OS(Mac) itself, where it worked perfectly, the changes to the CSS files were being reflected immediately in the browser.

Can someone please help me with this?

P.S. `inotify-tools` is already installed on ubuntu.

Comment: Any updates on this issue? I'm experiencing the same bug not on vagrant but with virtualbox or docker native.

Comment: Nah, just stopped using Vagrant. :)

Comment: Haha ok, just for your info, we're not alone ;) https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/issues/1409

Answer (score 0):

It might be related how exactly you share the folders between HOST and VM. Mounting propably will work only once and then you have to force files to reload, hence live reload will not work then.

Can you try live reload with files that are not shared or do you have any tool / script to synchronize folders?

Also remember that live reload relies on channels. Maybe there's something with your Internet connection on your VM that disables websocket connection.

Comment: Hey @PatNowak. Sorry, took me too long. I checked the above, but nothing works still. I tried to put the guest on the same network as the host, still no success. I tried force sync, didn't work.